req.file is showing undefined
As I am making an REST API, I am stuck here where I need to upload photo. I have made a multer middleware :
const multer = require("multer");
const currentDate = new Date()
let date = `${currentDate.getDate()}-${currentDate.getMonth()}-${currentDate.getFullYear()}`
let time = `${currentDate.getHours()}-${currentDate.getMinutes()}-${currentDate.getSeconds()}`;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, './images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        const ext = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
        callback(null, `${file.originalname}-${time}-${date}.${ext}`);
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
module.exports = {upload:upload,date:date,time:time}

and an api route :
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { upload } = require("../../middleware/imageUploader");

router.post("/", upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("File:", req.file);
    console.log("Body:", req.body);
    res.json({
      file: req.file,
      body: req.body,
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;

when I am testing my API I only got my body as response. And req.file is showing undefined


what happens if you try uploading the file with curl or some other tool

I have tried thunder client but its paid so It won't let me upload a file.
